# Convert the subscriber information in data extension (Marketing Cloud) into JSON message (in email content) and send it to external system

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Convert the subscriber information in data extension (Marketing Cloud) into JSON message and send it to external system   -  Can this be done using AMPScript or Do I need to rely on SSJS (Server Side Java Script).  Any thoughts please about the approach?  This is the script I've used so far to make a call. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
     %%[var @payload, @response
        set @payload = '{
        "email":"sendanemailtonishanth@gmail.com",
        "name":"Nishanth M",
        "ref":"1234"
        }'


     set @request = HTTPPost("https://www.trustpilot.com/evaluate-bgl/ABC.com?p=@payload")

    ]%%
     status code: %%=v(@request)=%%
<br><br>response: %%=v(@response)=%%    

       </span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of the [Concat apmscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm?search_text=redirect) for string concatenation which includes mixing strings and variables. In general it is easier to use SSJS for this type of thing, but will depend on your context/use case and knowledge. It's personal preference, but Ampscript is ok for simple uses such as the one you are describing.